# When browsing a website on my localhost using Google Chrome, can I access the names and content of my folders via inspect element?

Tags: google-chrome, localhost

I heard that Google Chrome can retrieve the html content and folders name of a website on localhost and that modifications can be saved directly from browser. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permanent changes? Or development "what if changes"?

IE Developer tools, and Firebug for Firefox can do on the fly "what if" changes for the session simply for troubleshooting and trying to isolate an issue. Chrome has the option too. All three are triggered with F12.

But it looks like Chrome has extensions that let you edit your HTML on the fly too.
http://www.addictivetips.com/internet-tips/pageedit-edit-any-website-within-chrome-view-changes-instantly/

There are probably similar items for Firefox, and maybe alternatives or more for Chrome.